# Reading Email Address from HTML file and sending email to Email Address via PHP file

Tags: php, html, email, variables, global

I am trying to do something fairly simple, which is enable a visitor of a website to email themselves a copy of the list of phone numbers of the website.

On a HTML file a simple text book asks for the user to enter text (email):

```
 <b> Email Address:
   <input type="text" name="emailaddress"/>
```

So far I have the following code on a PHP file:

```
 <a href="mailto:emailaddress">Email me the list of Phone Numbers</a>
```

However 'emailaddress' on the PHP file is not properly reading the input email address from the HTML page. When I change emailaddress on the PHP file to $emailaddress this ends up sending an email to '$emailaddress' instead of the input.

I would be extremely grateful for any help .

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the $_POST-Variable instead of a string "emailaddress".

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_POST['emailaddress']; ?>">Email me the list of Phone Numbers</a>
```

i suggest that you send your input field via POST. By the way, you should check your POST-Var to be a valid email-address.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the you are not actually using the email address given as input, instead you are using the string `emailaddress` in place of that.

Change the code to

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_GET['emailaddress']; ?>">Email me the list of Phone Numbers</a>
```

if you use GET method

or else change it to

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_POST['emailaddress'];">Email me the list of Phone Numbers</a>
```

if you use POST method